# Is this smart plug safe? only 2 pins

Tags: grounding, home-automation

I would like to use the TP-link HS110 to control my plant grow lights and monitor the energy usage. I have chosen this model specifically as it has many raspberry pi compatible hacks to avoid using their stupid app.

The problem: my local variation of this product has only 2 pins:
[image]

whereas the UK variant has 3 pins:

[image]

Are those 2 metal pieces acting as the grounding connection? is this safe to use with 1x 500W (LED) and 3x 600W HPS lights at the same time? (it is rated for 3.8kW).

I don't know much about electrical which is why I opted for a commercial product, I just dont want to accidentally kill myself and/or burn down my house :)

Comment: bare metal clips should be grounded. Easily checked with an ohm-meter.

Comment: The metal clips have the 'ground' symbol right next to them. I believe France uses that kind of plug (or something very similar) extensively.

Answer (score 5):

It seems from my own research that the local variant is a type F plug in which those two clips do act as the grounding connections. It is equivalently safe to the UK variant.

Comment: Yes. And it is commonly called a "schuko" socket.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko